# Consume Avro messages from Kafka using Java API

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming, kafka-consumer-api

I am consuming messages from a kafka topic in which the key and value are avro encoded, trying to convert the value part of the message which comes as byte[], to java object by using the KafkaAvroDecoder , complete code is below, (by the way if there is a better way that works please let me know to consume avro messages from kafka using java api) , but within the map method , I get stackover flow exception, and the exception is pasted below the code, need help to move forward.

Properties decoderProps = new Properties();
    decoderProps.put("schema.registry.url", SCHEMA_REG_URL);
    decoderProps.put(KafkaAvroDeserializerConfig.SPECIFIC_AVRO_READER_CONFIG, "true");

```
KafkaAvroDecoder decoder = new KafkaAvroDecoder(new VerifiableProperties(decoderProps));


SparkSession spark = SparkSession
    .builder()
    .appName("JavaCount1").master("local[2]")
    .config("spark.driver.extraJavaOptions", "-Xss4M")
    .getOrCreate();

Dataset<Message> ds1 = spark
    .readStream()
    .format("kafka")
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "ip address")
    .option("subscribe", "topicName")
    .option("startingOffsets", "earliest")
    .option("maxOffsetsPerTrigger", 1)
    .load().as(Encoders.bean(Message.class));

Dataset<UserEvent> ds2 = ds1.map(m-> {
    UserEvent data = (UserEvent)decoder.fromBytes(m.getValue());
     return data;
```

},Encoders.bean(UserEvent.class));

```
ds2.printSchema();

StreamingQuery query = ds2.writeStream()
    .outputMode("append")
    .format("console")
    .trigger(ProcessingTime.apply(15))
    .start();

query.awaitTermination();
```

. Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError at org.spark_project.guava.base.Preconditions.checkPositionIndex(Preconditions.java:354) at org.spark_project.guava.base.Preconditions.checkPositionIndex(Preconditions.java:334) at org.spark_project.guava.collect.AbstractIndexedListIterator.(AbstractIndexedListIterator.java:69) at org.spark_project.guava.collect.Iterators$12.(Iterators.java:1125) at org.spark_project.guava.collect.Iterators.forArray(Iterators.java:1125) at org.spark_project.guava.collect.RegularImmutableList.listIterator(RegularImmutableList.java:96) at org.spark_project.guava.collect.RegularImmutableAsList.listIterator(RegularImmutableAsList.java:54) at org.spark_project.guava.collect.ImmutableList.listIterator(ImmutableList.java:334) at org.spark_project.guava.collect.ImmutableList.iterator(ImmutableList.java:330) at org.spark_project.guava.collect.RegularImmutableMap$EntrySet.iterator(RegularImmutableMap.java:181) at org.spark_project.guava.collect.RegularImmutableMap$EntrySet.iterator(RegularImmutableMap.java:173) at org.spark_project.guava.reflect.TypeResolver.where(TypeResolver.java:97) at org.spark_project.guava.reflect.TypeResolver.accordingTo(TypeResolver.java:65) at org.spark_project.guava.reflect.TypeToken.resolveType(TypeToken.java:266) at org.spark_project.guava.reflect.TypeToken.resolveSupertype(TypeToken.java:279) at org.spark_project.guava.reflect.TypeToken.getSupertype(TypeToken.java:401) at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.JavaTypeInference$.elementType(JavaTypeInference.scala:142) at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.JavaTypeInference$.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$JavaTypeInference$inferDataType(JavaTypeInference.scala:111) at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.JavaTypeInference$anonfun$2.apply(JavaTypeInference.scala:127) at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.JavaTypeInference$anonfun$2.apply(JavaTypeInference.scala:125) at scala.collection.TraversableLike$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:245) at scala.collection.TraversableLike$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:245) at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33) at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:186) at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:245) at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.map(ArrayOps.scala:186) at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.JavaTypeInference$.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$JavaTypeInference$inferDataType(JavaTypeInference.scala:125) at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.JavaTypeInference$anonfun$2.apply(JavaTypeInference.scala:127) at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.JavaTypeInference$anonfun$2.apply(JavaTypeInference.scala:125) at scala.collection.TraversableLike$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:245) at scala.collection.TraversableLike$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:245) at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33) at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:186) at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:245) at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.map(ArrayOps.scala:186) at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.JavaTypeInference$.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$JavaTypeInference$inferDataType(JavaTypeInference.scala:125) at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.JavaTypeInference$anonfun$2.apply(JavaTypeInference.scala:127) at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.JavaTypeInference$anonfun$2.apply(JavaTypeInference.scala:125) at scala.collection.TraversableLike$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:245) at scala.collection.TraversableLike$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:245) at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33) at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:186) at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:245) at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.map(ArrayOps.scala:186) at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.JavaTypeInference$.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$JavaTypeInference$inferDataType(JavaTypeInference.scala:125) at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.JavaTypeInference$anonfun$2.apply(JavaTypeInference.scala:127) at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.JavaTypeInference$anonfun$2.apply(JavaTypeInference.scala:125) at scala.collection.TraversableLike$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:245) at scala.collection.TraversableLike$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:245) at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33) at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:186) at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:245) at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.map(ArrayOps.scala:186) at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.JavaTypeInference$.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$JavaTypeInference$inferDataType(JavaTypeInference.scala:125) at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.JavaTypeInference$anonfun$2.apply(JavaTypeInference.scala:127) at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.JavaTypeInference$anonfun$2.apply(JavaTypeInference.scala:125) at scala.collection.TraversableLike$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:245) at scala.collection.TraversableLike$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:245) at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33) at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:186) at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:245) at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.map(ArrayOps.scala:186) at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.JavaTypeInference$.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$JavaTypeInference$inferDataType(JavaTypeInference.scala:125) at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.JavaTypeInference$anonfun$2.apply(JavaTypeInference.scala:127) at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.JavaTypeInference$anonfun$2.apply(JavaTypeInference.scala:125) at scala.collection.TraversableLike$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:245) at scala.collection.TraversableLike$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:245) at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33) at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:186) at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:245) at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.map(ArrayOps.scala:186) at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.JavaTypeInference$.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$JavaTypeInference$inferDataType(JavaTypeInference.scala:125) at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.JavaTypeInference$anonfun$2.apply(JavaTypeInference.scala:127) at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.JavaTypeInference$anonfun$2.apply(JavaTypeInference.scala:125) at scala.collection.TraversableLike$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:245) at scala.collection.TraversableLike$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:245) at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33) at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:186) at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:245) at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.map(ArrayOps.scala:186) at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.JavaTypeInference$.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$JavaTypeInference$inferDataType(JavaTypeInference.scala:125) at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.JavaTypeInference$anonfun$2.apply(JavaTypeInference.scala:127) at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.JavaTypeInference$anonfun$2.apply(JavaTypeInference.scala:125) at scala.collection.TraversableLike$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:245) at scala.collection.TraversableLike$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:245) at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33) at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:186) at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:245) at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.map(ArrayOps.scala:186) at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.JavaTypeInference$.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$JavaTypeInference$inferDataType(JavaTypeInference.scala:125) at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.JavaTypeInference$anonfun$2.apply(JavaTypeInference.scala:127) at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.JavaTypeInference$anonfun$2.apply(JavaTypeInference.scala:125) at scala.collection.TraversableLike$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:245) at scala.collection.TraversableLike$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:245) at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33) at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:186) at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:245) at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.map(ArrayOps.scala:186) at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.JavaTypeInference$.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$JavaTypeInference$inferDataType(JavaTypeInference.scala:125) at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.JavaTypeInference$anonfun$2.apply(JavaTypeInference.scala:127) at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.JavaTypeInference$anonfun$2.apply(JavaTypeInference.scala:125) at scala.collection.TraversableLike$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:245) at scala.collection.TraversableLike$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:245) at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33) at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:186) at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:245) at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.map(ArrayOps.scala:186) at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.JavaTypeInference$.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$JavaTypeInference$inferDataType(JavaTypeInference.scala:125) at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.JavaTypeInference$anonfun$2.apply(JavaTypeInference.scala:127) at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.JavaTypeInference$anonfun$2.apply(JavaTypeInference.scala:125) at scala.collection.TraversableLike$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:245) at scala.collection.TraversableLike$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:245) at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33) at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:186) at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:245) at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.map(ArrayOps.scala:186) at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.JavaTypeInference$.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$JavaTypeInference$inferDataType(JavaTypeInference.scala:125) at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.JavaTypeInference$anonfun$2.apply(JavaTypeInference.scala:127) at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.JavaTypeInference$anonfun$2.apply(JavaTypeInference.scala:125) at scala.collection.TraversableLike$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:245) at scala.collection.TraversableLike$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:245) at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33) at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:186) at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:245) at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.map(ArrayOps.scala:186) at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.JavaTypeInference$.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$JavaTypeInference$inferDataType(JavaTypeInference.scala:125) at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.JavaTypeInference$anonfun$2.apply(JavaTypeInference.scala:127) at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.JavaTypeInference$anonfun$2.apply(JavaTypeInference.scala:125) at scala.collection.TraversableLike$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:245) at scala.collection.TraversableLike$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:245) at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33) at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:186) at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:245) at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.map(ArrayOps.scala:186) at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.JavaTypeInference$.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$JavaTypeInference$inferDataType(JavaTypeInference.scala:125) at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.JavaTypeInference$anonfun$2.apply(JavaTypeInference.scala:127) at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.JavaTypeInference$anonfun$2.apply(JavaTypeInference.scala:125) at scala.collection.TraversableLike$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:245) at scala.collection.TraversableLike$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:245) at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33) at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:186) at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:245) at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.map(ArrayOps.scala:186) at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.JavaTypeInference$.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$JavaTypeInference$inferDataType(JavaTypeInference.scala:125) at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.JavaTypeInference$anonfun$2.apply(JavaTypeInference.scala:127) at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.JavaTypeInference$anonfun$2.apply(JavaTypeInference.scala:125) at scala.collection.TraversableLike$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:245) at scala.collection.TraversableLike$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:245) at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33) at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:186) at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:245) at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.map(ArrayOps.scala:186) at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.JavaTypeInference$.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$JavaTypeInference$inferDataType(JavaTypeInference.scala:125) at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.JavaTypeInference$anonfun$2.apply(JavaTypeInference.scala:127) at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.JavaTypeInference$anonfun$2.apply(JavaTypeInference.scala:125) at scala.collection.TraversableLike$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:245) at scala.collection.TraversableLike$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:245) at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33) at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:186) at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:245) at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.map(ArrayOps.scala:186) at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.JavaTypeInference$.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$JavaTypeInference$inferDataType(JavaTypeInference.scala:125) at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.JavaTypeInference$anonfun$2.apply(JavaTypeInference.scala:127) at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.JavaTypeInference$anonfun$2.apply(JavaTypeInference.scala:125) at scala.collection.TraversableLike$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:245) at scala.collection.TraversableLike$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:245) at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33) at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:186) at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:245) at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.map(ArrayOps.scala:186) at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.JavaTypeInference$.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$JavaTypeInference$

Comment: Too difficult to comment ,  but for a understanding you can have a look at the sample code with Integration Test . 

http://bytepadding.com/big-data/spark/avro/avro-serialization-de-serialization-using-confluent-schema-registry/

Comment: let me take a look